# Unable to load external css file with node/express - 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I have got to configure an express app in an architecture that look like this:

```
![my architecture][1]


Build
Core/pulse.core/assets/styles/global.css
app.js
Express_app
  views/home.jade
  controller/routes.js
node_modules
```

my app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express();

html_templates = __dirname + '/Express_app';

app.set('views', html_templates + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use("/Core", express.static(__dirname + 'Core/Pulse.Core/Assets/Styles/'));


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("express has started on port 3000");
});

require('./Express_app/controller/routes.js')(app);
```

in my home.jade file, i have:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href=levelarbo+"../../Core/Pulse.Core/Assets/Styles/global.css")
```

My html is loading fine, however, i am getting a 404 for my css file, please help. I have been stuck on this for hours :(

Comment: Try `app.use("/Core", express.static(__dirname + '/Core'));`

Comment: i still get a 404 on this: localhost:3000/Core/Pulse.Core/Assets/Styles/global.css :(

Comment: Make sure it's not a case sensitivity issue... check the casing of the path in the URL matches the file system.

Comment: You are absolutely right !! got it working - accepted answer :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use("/Core", express.static(__dirname + 'Core/Pulse.Core/Assets/Styles/'));
```

Should be (note the location of the `/`)...

```
app.use("/Core", express.static(__dirname + '/Core'));
```

The casing in the URL should match the casing in the file system. If the actual path is `Core/pulse.core/assets/styles/global.css`, the jade file should read...

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href=levelarbo+"../../Core/pulse.core/assets/styles/global.css")
```